# "DWORD (32-bit) Value" or ""Qword (32-bit) Value" - which one should I configure in Windows 64-bit registry?

Tags: 2010, development, permissions, security

["DisableLoopbackCheck & SharePoint: What every admin and developer should know"](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx) advises to disable ("infamous") "loopback check" completely on dev machine by following

- ["You receive error 401.1 when you browse a Web site that uses Integrated Authentication and is hosted on IIS 5.1 or a later version"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861)

The latter tells:

- "4. Right-click Lsa, point to New, and then click DWORD Value"

Well, right-clicking "New" on "LSA" in Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter doesn't have "DWORD Value" but only:

- "DWORD (32-bit) Value"
- "Qword (64-bit) Value"

Which one should I set?

Comment: you should dissociate the storage size of the value from the processor architecture. Running on 64 bits does not means you have to store values in 64 bits. I guess this is simpler for Microsoft because they have a single method to read this value that returns an int, and easier for us, because the same procedure applies for all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DisableLoopbackCheck should be a "DWORD (32-bit) Value"